# I can't seem to be able to use openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using python 3.8.2 (latest right now). I'm trying to use openpyxl.

I Installed it with pip through cmd without any errors, but when I try to import the workbook it doesn't work.

This is the code I wrote:

```py
from openpyxl import workbook
```

This is the output I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Atom Projects\Agileroo\Python\Course 6\openpyxl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import workbook
  File "D:\Atom Projects\Agileroo\Python\Course 6\openpyxl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import workbook
ImportError: cannot import name 'workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\Atom Projects\Agileroo\Python\Course 6\openpyxl.py)
```

I tried reinstalling python, still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error seems to be the name of the file.

You have named the file `openpyxl.py` because of which import command does not actually go into the libraries to find out `openpyxl` or `workbook`, it just looks into your file.

Just change that name to something else.

If you haven't installed the library yet, try installing [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-openpyxl) using `pip` before start using it. Run the below command to do this:

```sh
pip install openpyxl

# OR

pip3 install openpyxl

# Even better. (Assuming python3 command invokes python3.8 in your system)

python3 -m pip install openpyxl
```

**TIP:** Never use reserved keywords/library name etc as your file/folder name.